# Como saber si un evento personalizado consume muchos recursos

Tags: java, eventos

Cree un evento personalizado en java que es equivalente al mouseover en javascript.
Despues utilizo otra clase la cual hereda de la que contiene el evento personalizado, posteriormente esta clase la agrego a una ventana 100 veces y el programa queda demasiado lento.
Mi pregunta es ¿como puedo optimizar el evento para que sea mas eficiente y no sea tan lento el programa?.

Les dejo el codigo de la clase del evento personalizado.

```
   public class Componente extends Component implements Runnable{

protected static Point posicion;
private RatonEncimaEscuchador interfaceCodigo;
private boolean continuar=true;
private Thread hilo;

public Componente() {
    super();
    setVisible(true);
    hilo=new Thread(this);
    hilo.start();
}


public void agregarRatonEncimaEscuchador(RatonEncimaEscuchador evento){
    interfaceCodigo=evento;  

}


public void run() {
    Point vertice=null;
    boolean banderaRun=false;
    while(continuar) {
        if(this.isShowing()) {
            vertice=this.getLocationOnScreen();
            banderaRun=true;
        }
        int ancho=this.getWidth(),alto=this.getHeight();
        posicion=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        if(banderaRun&&interfaceCodigo!=null&&estaDentro(posicion,ancho,alto,vertice)) {
            interfaceCodigo.ratonEncima(this);
        }

    }

}


public boolean estaDentro(Point p,int ancho, int alto,Point vertice) {

    if(p.x>vertice.x&&p.x<(vertice.x+ancho)&&p.y>vertice.y&&p.y<(vertice.y+alto)) {

       return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

Comment: @BetaM esta censurado mencionar a Dios en este sitio???

Comment: No, pero no aporta en nada a tu pregunta y a exponer tus dudas y avance por eso lo edité